# Float value not the same which the function is used in another translation unit

Tags: c, floating-point, function-call

Here's my problem: I have two files, one containing my `main()` :

```
int main()
{
  float a;

  a = 90;
  test(a);
}
```

and the other one containing a `test()` function :

```
float test(float a)
{
  printf("a : %f\n", a);
}
```

So, I compile these files (`gcc test.c main.c`) and I execute the binary.

But why do the output is

> a : 0.0000

and not

> a : 90.0000

as expected?

Comment: are you providing the correct prototype?

Comment: Oh thanks ! the output is correct now

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [comments below the actual post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291240/float-value-not-the-same-in-another-file-c/41291359#comment69785145_41291240), missing to provide the proper signature (forward declaration / prototype) of a function to all the different translation unit using the function will result in a *fallback* to the function with a signature of

- Returning an `int` (obsolete in latest standard)
- Accepting any number of arguments with no type-checking.

In this case, then, the function call

```
test(a);
```

will be interpreted as a call to a function, returning `int` and passing one `int` argument which is actually a mismatch (expected `int` and actual `float` type), causing the [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), producing unwated result.